# Finding difficulty trying to get the jsTree plugin to initialize in a closed state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Afternoon Everyone.

We're setting up a permissions tree for user profiles.
We use the jsTree plugin found here: [jQuery jsTree Plugin](http://www.jstree.com/)

Over version is: 3.1.0
Their current version is: 3.1.0

Here's our usage:

```
/* Initialize any jsTress passed in. */
$( "." + section + "-panel-" + panel ).find( "div[class*='jstree']" ).each(function(){
    $(this).jstree( {   "core"      : { "data" : $.parseJSON( $(this).prev().html() ) },
                        "plugins"   : [ "checkbox","wholerow" ]  
                    } );

    /* Try to force close-all tree nodes. */
    $(this).jstree( "close_all",-1 );
})
```

We manually try to force close all nodes here, although it doesn't work.
The JSON data passed into the initialization method includes node state attributes.

See actual data sample:

```
[
{ 
    "id":"ADMIN",
    "text":"ADMIN",
    "state":
    {
        "selected":false
    },
    "children":
    [
        {   
            "id":"ADMIN_ADD_STAFF",
            "text":"ADMIN_ADD_STAFF",
            "state":
            {
                "opened":false,
                "disabled":false,
                "selected":true
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"ADMIN_NEW_MSG",
            "text":"ADMIN_NEW_MSG",
            "state":
            {
                "opened":false,
                "disabled":false,
                "selected":true
            }
        }
        /* Truncated here for brevity of question. */
        /* See link below for complete data object. */
    ]
}
]
```

See [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Ff3EgfRp) for copy of complete data object.

As you can see, the `opened` attrib is always false, yet we find the nodes always initialize in the opened state.

[image: Screen shot of jsTree immediately after initialization]

Nodes will close if you manually close them.
Note: We are not using the plugin that enables node-state persistence in browser.

Just can't seem to see why the nodes won't initialize as closed...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to call `close_all` after the `ready.jstree` event has fired:

```
$(this),jstree(...).on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
  data.instance.close_all();
});
```

You can also simply configure jsTree not to expand the selected nodes onload:
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=expand&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.expand_selected_onload

```
$(this).jstree({
  core : {
    expand_selected_onload : false,
    ...
```

Best regards,
Ivan

Comment: Thanks @vakata. We actually found that last night ... how simple. How frustrating we over-looked it. Working as expected now. Great work!